# App publishing on play store

Tags: phonegap-build

Is there any way to convert phonegap app into native android app so that it can be published to play store as I heard that play store does not accept apps made by phonegap AIDE?

Answer (score 1):

You "heard" wrong.

Build it in Phonegap for Android, sign it, upload it.